# How can I check for a macro's existence/permission from my add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I can call a macro from within my add-in with the following code:

```
Application.Run(MACRO_NAME);
```

Where `Application` is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`.  I would like to be able to check to see if the macro exists (and if I have permission to run it) before making the call to `Run()`.  Right now I am simply putting the call in a `try` block but I hate to use exception handling for program control.

Is there a way to see what macros are available to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always check for a specific module by looking into 
this.Application.VBProject.VBComponents (search by VBIDE.VBComponent.Name)

You can also search for a string in a VBComponent's code, to make sure it's there. Not much more you can do.

Howewer, a try-catch is a perfectly fine approach. So many things could go bad that you would need exception handling anyway. I would stick to it.